# Aggregate with output length same as Data Frame length

Tags: r

I need to aggregate a number between two factors, but I need the output of the aggregation to be a a vector the same length as the original data frame, rather than a summary table, so I can attach it and eventually output it as an .xlsx report.

```
data <- data.frame(A = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"), 
                   B = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,2), 
X=c(0.17,0.15,0.30,0.36,0.47,0.43,0.50,0.38,0.38,0.47,0.40,0.29,0.46,0.14,0.03,0.34,0.42,0.35,0.19,0.27))
```

I need to sum X grouped by both A, and unique combination of A and B, and append it to the data frame, so that it looks like this

[image: a data frame with aggregates appended]

I'm aware of the aggregate function, which calculates the quantities I need but outputs them in a summary table format which I can't then append to the data frame.

So far this is the only method I've come up with - it takes 10 minutes to run on my actual, 13000 row data frame, it seems very hacky and it also seems to be causing some other bugs that I'm hoping redoing this bit will solve.

```
TBL <- as.data.frame(table(data$A, data$B))
colnames(TBL) <- c("A", "B", "Freq")
#contains every unique combination of A and B

for (i in 1:NROW(TBL)){
  INDEX <- which(data$A == TBL$A[i] & data$B == TBL$B[i])
  Data$`X by AB`[INDEX] <- sum(data$X[INDEX])
}
```

Comment: Your input data and expected output don't seem to match. `data` has two rows for `A = A` (poor choice of column names), whereas your output has 6 rows. Is that a typo? That aside, it sounds like you're after `ave`.

Comment: Yes that was a typo - fixed now. I changed the made-up data halfway through writing this to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, and forgot to change it in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need to `group_by` `A` AND `A` and `B` and get `sum` of `X`. With `dplyr`, we can use two `group_by` statements with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  mutate(XbyAB = sum(X)) %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(XbyA = sum(X))

#  A       B    X XbyAB  XbyA
# <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A      1  0.12  0.12  0.46
# 2 A      2  0.34  0.34  0.46
# 3 B      1  0.5   0.9   1.59
# 4 B      1  0.4   0.9   1.59
# 5 B      3  0.69  0.69  1.59
# 6 C      1  0.42  0.42  0.5 
# 7 C      2  0.08  0.08  0.5 
# 8 D      2  0.9   0.9   0.9 
# 9 E      3  0.74  0.74  0.94
#10 E      4  0.2   0.2   0.94
```

Or in base R two `ave` with `transform`

```
transform(data, XbyAB = ave(X, A, B, FUN = sum), XbyA = ave(X, A, FUN = sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution.

```
library("data.table")
data <- as.data.table(data)
```

First, let's sum X by A:

```
data[, .( `X by A`=sum(X) ), by=A]
# A X by A
# 1: A   1.88
# 2: B   3.02
# 3: C   1.60
```

We merge this summary data.table with the original one on column A:

```
data[data[, .( `X by A`=sum(X) ), by=A], on=.(A)]
```

We can also summarize and then merge on two columns:

```
 data[data[, .( `X by AB`=sum(X) ), by=.(A, B)], on=.(A, B)]
```

The problem is, to the uninitiated, the `data.table` syntax isn't very readable, but I swear by its speed (as compared to dplyr and especially `data.frame`). Although the difference shouldn't be very noticeable with 13K rows.